# Split a text after a maximum of X words

Tags: javascript, regex

I struggled to find a solution to my problem and though it would be great to share it. Here is the problem:

I have a text, it may include any kind of punctuation. I want to split it in two parts:

1. a maximum of X words

   - including the punctation attached to the final word such as a dot or a comma
2. the end of the text

   - starting with the spacing between the two parts

Here are some examples:

```
str = "one two, three, quatro 5! : six sept  ocho nine 10!"

splitAfterXWords(str, 2)
// ["one two,", "three, quatro 5! : six sept  ocho nine 10!"]

splitAfterXWords(str, 5)
// ["one two, three, quatro 5!", " : six sept  ocho nine 10!"]

splitAfterXWords(str, 20)
// ["one two, three, quatro 5! : six sept  ocho nine 10!", ""]

splitAfterXWords(str, 6)
// ["one two, three, quatro 5! : six", " sept  ocho nine 10!"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that does the work:

```
function splitAfterXWords(to_split, words){
    regex = new RegExp("(([\\s;:!,.?\"'’]*[^\\s]+){" + words + "})(.*)")
    result = regex.exec(to_split)
    return result ? [result[1], to_split.substr(result[1].length)] : [to_split, '']
}
```

You can see it working on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xhSW/10/).

Improvements and comments are welcomed !

Comment: Have you considered using `\b` to detect word boundaries instead of a whitelist of punctuation?

Comment: I though about it but did not figure out how to use it in this case. Any idea?

Comment: I recently had to change this code. THIS DOES NOT SCALE AT ALL. Splitting after 20 words works like a charme but, surprisingly, 100 words crashes the current tab. I have no idea why though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt on getting `n` words from a given sentence:

```
var regexp = /\s*\S+\/;
function truncateToNWords(s, n) {
   var l=0;
   if (s == null || n<= 0) return l;
   for (var i=0; i<n && (match = regexp.exec(s)) != null; i++) {
      s = s.substring(match[0].length);
      l += match[0].length;
   }
   return l;
}

// your sentence
var s = "one two, three, quatro 5!: six sept  ocho nine 10!";

l = truncateToNWords(s, 2);
console.log([s.substring(0, l), s.substring(l)]);

l = truncateToNWords(s, 5);
console.log([s.substring(0, l), s.substring(l)]);

l = truncateToNWords(s, 6);
console.log([s.substring(0, l), s.substring(l)]);

l = truncateToNWords(s, 20);
console.log([s.substring(0, l), s.substring(l)]);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
["one two,", " three, quatro 5!: six sept ocho nine 10!"]
["one two, three, quatro 5!:", " six sept ocho nine 10!"]
["one two, three, quatro 5!: six", " sept ocho nine 10!"]
["one two, three, quatro 5!: six sept ocho nine 10!", ""]
```

Comment: Not bad except there is a small difference in the output. The first part contains the spacing following the last word : `one two, ` should be `one two,` without space.

Comment: I think you could just switch the two terms of your regexp: `/\s*\S+/`